# Conditional Sequence of Events

Tags: c

Im trying to write a function that scans in IP addresses on user input and has three main conditions:

1. If the IP address is valid, `valid_addresses += 1`
2. If the IP address is precisely `-1.-1.-1.-1` then stop scanning for any further IP addresses and return `valid_addresses` (should contain the number of valid addresses).
3. If the IP address contains any value that is either below 0 or above 255, `printf("Invalid input.\n")` but continue scanning for further IP addresses (don't terminate the loop).

My current attempt is simply printing "Invalid input":

**Main:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int LENGTH = 5; /* Tells the function how many IP addresses the user needs to provide on input */
char dot; /* Stores the points between digits */

  struct ipaddr{ /* Making the ip address struct */
    int octet1;
    int octet2;
    int octet3;
    int octet4;
  }; typedef struct ipaddr ipaddr_t;

int get_valid_ip_addrs(ipaddr_t addr_array[], int addr_array_len); /* Function prototype */

int main(){


  struct ipaddr addr_array[LENGTH]; /* Variable declaration */

  get_valid_ip_addrs(addr_array, LENGTH); /* Function call */

}
```

**Function definition**

```
    int get_valid_ip_addrs(ipaddr_t addr_array[], int addr_array_len){
          int valid_inputs = 0, i, k;
          for(i = 0; i < addr_array_len; i++){
          scanf("%i%c%i%c%i%c%i", &addr_array[i].octet1, &dot, &addr_array[i].octet2, &dot, 
                                    &addr_array[i].octet3, &dot, &addr_array[i].octet4);

/* Condition 1. (if the address is valid) */

          for(k = 0; k < addr_array_len; k++){ 
            if(addr_array[k].octet1 > 0 && addr_array[k].octet1 < 256 &&
               addr_array[k].octet2 > 0 && addr_array[k].octet2 < 256 &&
               addr_array[k].octet3 > 0 && addr_array[k].octet3 < 256 &&
               addr_array[k].octet4 > 0 && addr_array[k].octet4 < 256){
              valid_inputs = valid_inputs + 1;
              }

/* Condition 2 (if the address is -1.-1.-1.-1) */

           else if(addr_array[k].octet1 == -1 && 
                    addr_array[k].octet2 == -1 &&
                    addr_array[k].octet3 == -1 &&
                    addr_array[k].octet4 == -1){
              return valid_inputs;
              }

/* Condition 3 - if the address is invalid */

           else if(addr_array[k].octet1 < 0 || addr_array[k].octet1 > 255 ||
                   addr_array[k].octet2 < 0 || addr_array[k].octet2 > 255 ||
                   addr_array[k].octet3 < 0 || addr_array[k].octet3 > 255 ||
                   addr_array[k].octet4 < 0 || addr_array[k].octet4 > 255){
             printf("Invalid input.\n");
                }
           }

          }

          return valid_inputs;

        }
```

I cant seem to figure out why my program doesn't do what i'm expecting it to do, any help for a beginner is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your input and what output are you expecting?

Comment: Hint: check for the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: @user7176709 it depends on the user input - see conditions 1, 2 and 3 at the top of the question

Comment: Alright, one thing right off the bat, You're already running a loop in which you expect a scanf, within that, you nest another loop which goes from 0 to the `addr_arr_len`. In your first case even when you have only 1 element your inner loop goes to `5` in your case when you have only 1 element right now. I suggest you get rid of the inner `k` loop

Comment: `int res = scanf("%i.%i.%i.%i", ...)` would be better than scanning for the `'.'` (where you overwrite `char dot` and don't check it anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
typedef enum
{
    IP_GET_OK,
    IP_GET_ERROR,
    IP_GET_END,
}IP_STATUS_t;


IP_STATUS_t getIP4(char *buff, int *ip4)
{
    IP_STATUS_t result = IP_GET_ERROR;
    if(buff && ip4 && fgets(buff, 32, stdin))
    {
        if(sscanf(buff, "%d.%d.%d.%d", &ip4[0], &ip4[1], &ip4[2], &ip4[3]) == 4)
        {
            int allminusone = 1;
            for(size_t index = 0; index < 4; index++)
            {
                allminusone = allminusone && (ip4[index] == -1);
            }
            if(allminusone)
            {
                result = IP_GET_END;
            }
            else
            {
                result = IP_GET_OK;
                for(size_t index = 0; index < 4; index++)
                {
                    if(ip4[index] < 0 || ip4[index] > 0xff )
                    {
                        result = IP_GET_ERROR;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What does `if(ip[0] == ip[1] ==ip[2] == ip[3] == -1)` do?

Comment: Sorry, and what happens to the dots?

Comment: @WeatherVane dots were lost in the deep space.,

Comment: any DV reason? Ot just the moon phase

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra inner `k` loop. in which in the first case you only have one input but you still iterate over all the elements for which the behavior may be undefined.

```c
int get_valid_ip_addrs(ipaddr_t addr_array[], int addr_array_len){
          int valid_inputs = 0, i, k;
          for(i = 0; i < addr_array_len; i++){
          scanf("%d%c%d%c%d%c%d", &addr_array[i].octet1, &dot,
                  &addr_array[i].octet2, &dot,&addr_array[i].octet3, &dot, &addr_array[i].octet4);
          /* Condition 1. (if the address is valid) */
            if(addr_array[i].octet1 > 0 && addr_array[i].octet1 < 256 &&
               addr_array[i].octet2 > 0 && addr_array[i].octet2 < 256 &&
               addr_array[i].octet3 > 0 && addr_array[i].octet3 < 256 &&
               addr_array[i].octet4 > 0 && addr_array[i].octet4 < 256){
              valid_inputs = valid_inputs + 1;
              }
           /* Condition 2 (if the address is -1.-1.-1.-1) */
           else if(addr_array[i].octet1 == -1 && 
                    addr_array[i].octet2 == -1 &&
                    addr_array[i].octet3 == -1 &&
                    addr_array[i].octet4 == -1){
              return valid_inputs;
              }
           /* Condition 3 - if the address is invalid */
           else if(addr_array[i].octet1 < 0 || addr_array[i].octet1 > 255 ||
                   addr_array[i].octet2 < 0 || addr_array[i].octet2 > 255 ||
                   addr_array[i].octet3 < 0 || addr_array[i].octet3 > 255 ||
                   addr_array[i].octet4 < 0 || addr_array[i].octet4 > 255){
             printf("Invalid input.\n");
                }
          }
          return valid_inputs;
}
```